# Unable to install node modules in Nestjs project

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, nestjs

I cloned a nest.js application from github. I am trying to install node modules but when I am trying to run comment npm install, the application makes an error.

```
npm WARN tar TAR_ENTRY_ERROR EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\ThesisArtValueMyCode\Clone_art_values_api\node_modules\moment\locale\en-SG.js.DELETE.4db65193375d77bd6793cd19a8c5da63'
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path D:\ThesisArtValueMyCode\Clone_art_values_api\node_modules\sha3
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp info using node@12.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.8 found at "C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.8.31005.135) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - "Visual Studio C++ core features" missing
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - not found
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:310:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\rezau\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd D:\ThesisArtValueMyCode\Clone_art_values_api\node_modules\sha3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rezau\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-09T08_49_40_737Z-debug.log
```

The above error shows all time. I do not understand how to solve this. I updated my npm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio & install Visual Studio C++ core features from it then try again.

Download link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=Community&rel=16

> You'll see the Visual C++ build tools option in the installer, just select it & let the default components get installed, you won't need optional components as I do so just ignore the ticked feature on the right-hand side.

[image: image showing installation components needed]

Hope this helps & please don't mind bad sketch skills!